# touchbar does not work in root account

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, touch-bar

macOS High Sierra, macbook pro 2017. Can be duplicated on fresh install of macOS High Sierra on another macbook pro 2017.

Problem: The touch bar remains like it is in the login window and does not have application control/general control on it when I logged into the root account. There are reasons that I need to use the root account that cannot be currently addressed using an admin accounts. This behavior does not exist for other user accounts.

[image]

Remains like this whatever I do. Pressing fn can reveal F1-F12.

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the question here? And I assume with root account you mean the unix `root` account, right?

Comment: Then disable the root account. Hey presto, you've solved your problem and increased the security of your Mac.

Comment: Why do you think you need to log into the GUI as root?  Let's fix the **actual** problem.

Comment: I need root account in order to use Finder as root and read/modify system files without password authentication or changing permissions. I'm not too concerned with the security of my mac. From multiple tests and attempts to fix the "actual" problem, my conclusion is that the only solution is to use root account.

Comment: Please update your question with the details then.